# Elasticsearch get hits for some records and aggregation's buckets for others

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a complicated Elasticsearch query that contains aggregations, and I want to get hits result for some records (based on a field: "**application_name**") and aggregation's buckets for others. The issue is that for the events (that I want to get buckets for) I don't want to have them in hits, and if I put "size = 0" I will not be able to get the other ordinary events from hits.

Is there any way to set size=0 depending on application_name, or other solution that can help me with my problem?

PS. For the moment I created two queries, one that I get hits from and the other for aggregation, but I want to do that at once if possible.

My query (simplified):

````
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "application_name": "app_x"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "application_name": "app_y"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "date": {
                    "from": "2020-08-24",
                    "to": "2020-08-24",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "so": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "so",
        "size": 1000,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "R-agg": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "task_name": {
                "value": "Rapp",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          }
...```
````

Comment: How many hits do you need for each application?

Comment: Maximum 1000, or 0 for some of them